# Azure SQL MI: The requested server principal already exists on Managed Instance

Tags: azure-sql-managed-instance, azure-managed-database

In my SQL MI i have a ad group (called Group A) which was already assigned to the Active Directory Admin through Portal. I'm trying to update/replace that with a new group called Group B.

When I tried I get the error like

> {"error":{"code":"ServerPrincipalAlreadyExists","message":"The
> requested server principal already exists on Managed Instance.
> Consider dropping the server principal and retrying operation."}}.

When I tried to add another new group called **Group C** it works. But the issue with **Group B** still exist

Questions:

- How come the new group B has been already exists on the MI ?
- How to remove the service principal ?

P.S I tried by removing the existing group from the active directory admin and add the new group B still the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether group B exists among service_principals and drop it. You can check that by looking at server_principals table https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-server-principals-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15. If it exist you need to drop sp(probably you added it as a login and thus it is server principal).

Comment: thanks for your response. Can you help me on the query on how to safely drop the spn from `sys.server_principals`? Is this  `DROP LOGIN [spn_name]` is enough ?

Comment: Yes It should be enough